# XOR Python Text Encryption/Decryption

Tags: python, python-2.7, encryption

I know there is a built in xor operator that can be imported in Python. 
I'm trying to execute the xor encryption/decryption. So far I have:

```
 def xor_attmpt():
    message = raw_input("Enter message to be ciphered: ")
    cipher = []
    for i in message:
        cipher.append(bin(ord(i))[2::])#add the conversion of the letters/characters
#in your message from ascii to binary withoout the 0b in the front to your ciphered message list
    cipher = "".join(cipher) 
    privvyKey = raw_input("Enter the private key: ")
    keydecrypt = []
    for j in privvyKey:
        keydecrypt.append(bin(ord(j))[2::]) #same
    keydecrypt = "".join(keydecrypt )#same

    print "key is '{0}'" .format(keydecrypt) #substitute values in string
    print "encrypted text is '{0}'" .format(cipher)
    from operator import xor
    for letter in message:
        print xor(bool(cipher), bool(keydecrypt))
```

This:

```
>  for letter in message:
    print xor(bool(cipher), bool(keydecrypt))
```

is where my python starts to go wrong.

The ouput looks like this

```
    Enter message to be ciphered: hello
Enter the private key: \@154>
key is '10111001000000110001110101110100111110'
encrypted text is '11010001100101110110011011001101111'
False
False
False
False
False
```

What I'm messing up on is trying to get these two binary(key and encrypted) to be compared and give true(1) or false(being 0). The xor should then give me a resulting 1 and 0 binary list from comparing the two. Any input?

Comment: How is your private key represented in Python? Integer, string of bytes, something else? Ultimately you're looking at the `^` operator for bitwise XOR but you need to make sure your arguments are compatible.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a variation of the code example from [XOR Cipher Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher):

```
def xor(data, key): 
    return bytearray(a^b for a, b in zip(*map(bytearray, [data, key])))
```

Example (Python 2):

```
>>> one_time_pad = 'shared secret' 
>>> plaintext = 'unencrypted' 
>>> ciphertext = xor(plaintext, one_time_pad) 
>>> ciphertext 
bytearray(b'\x06\x06\x04\x1c\x06\x16Y\x03\x11\x06\x16') 
>>> decrypted = xor(ciphertext, one_time_pad) 
>>> decrypted
bytearray(b'unencrypted')
>>> plaintext == str(decrypted)
True
```

Comment: This will truncate data so you need something like `itertools.cycle` for the secret key.

Comment: @HTF no. Think, why the variable is called `one_time_pad`. To be explicit, a ValueError may be raised if `len(data)>len(key)`

Answer (score 7):

Code below works both ways and does not need length checking as cycle is used.

```
from itertools import cycle, izip
cryptedMessage = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in izip(message, cycle(key)))
```

Comment: Use builtin zip for Python 3

Answer (score 5):

```
somecode = 'asdfln3j34tnonfdkjnflksdfnla'
message = 'this is my message'

def str_xor(s1, s2):
 return "".join([chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for (c1,c2) in zip(s1,s2)])

encoded = str_xor(message, somecode)
# encoded == '\x15\x1b\r\x15L\x07@J^MT\x03\n\x1d\x15\x05\x0c\x0f'
decoded = str_xor(encoded, somecode)
# decoded == 'this is my message'
```

This is a naive / minimalistic implementation without error checking. Here len(somecode) >= len(message) is required.

Comment: thank you. Even if this has no error checking, it is a solution in my eyes! :D One question, what exactly does the "".join do?

Comment: "".join(['a','b','c']) == 'abc'

Comment: oh. I've been seeing this in multiple places regarding python. thnx

Comment: Nitpicky, but I would use `"".join(chr(ord(s1) ^ ord(s2)) for (s1, s2) in zip(somecode, message))` - `zip` is generally more Pythonic for lockstep iterating over two sequences than `range(len(...))`. Though pay attention to what you want to happen if the sequences are of different lengths, using either `zip` or the `range` call.

Comment: Peter: yes, I agree. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 4):

for **Python 3**

```
from itertools import cycle

cryptedMessage = ''.join(chr(ord(c)^ord(k)) for c,k in zip(message, cycle(key)))
```