# Xor bits in python

Tags: python, string, xor, bit, des

Well I have an assignment to implement DES and I chose python, only problem is I can't figure out how to XOR bits of a String or Byte String, I can manually XOR them if only I can manage to read the 1s and 0s in them.

Example:

```
s1 = b'abc'
s2 = b'efg'

s3 = XOR(s1,s2) // my own method
```

How can I XOR them or how can I get the binary values of 1s and 0s that represent them?

If you use any python methods explain them, I'm relatively new to this language.

Comment: repeated question?

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612720/how-to-do-bitwise-exclusive-or-of-two-strings-in-python][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612720/how-to-do-bitwise-exclusive-or-of-two-strings-in-python

Comment: i think it is, but i got alot of questions about implementing these methods since i'm really new to python and generally wanna know more about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to `zip` your strings then use `ord` (in `python 2`) and `^` for each of characters :

```
>>> s1 = b'abc'
>>> s2 = b'efg'
>>> ''.join(chr(ord(i)^ord(j)) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
'\x04\x04\x04'
```

the [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) function retuen value of the byte when the argument is an 8-bit string.But if you are using `python 3` you dont need `ord` :

```
>>> ''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
'\x04\x04\x04'
```

> Since bytes objects are sequences of integers (akin to a tuple), for a bytes object b, `b[0]` will be an integer, while `b[0:1]` will be a bytes object of length 1. (This contrasts with text strings, where both indexing and slicing will produce a string of length 1)

```
example :

>>> s1[0]
97
>>> s1[0:1]
b'a'
```

---

and if you want to convert back your strings you need to firs convert the `XOR`ed string to binary you can do it by `binascii.a2b_qp` function :

```
>>> import binascii 
>>> s=''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
>>> s4=binascii.a2b_qp(s)
>>> ''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s4))
'efg'
```

Comment: i'm not really familiar with the ord and python syntax, firstly i'm getting "TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found" is it because i'm using python 3.x and secondly does
join(chr(ord(i)^ord(j)) for i,j in zip(s1,s2)) = perform ord(i) xor ord (j) for the range in zip?

Comment: @Newbie yep, in python 3 you dont need `ord` ! see the edit !

Comment: okay i know that i shouldn't ask this, but can u XOR them back to return s1?
s3 =''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s1,s2))
s4 =''.join(chr(i^j) for i,j in zip(s3,s2))
(s3 is printing 3 chars which i can't copy here)
this isn't working

Comment: I love you, thanks alot for all your troubles with this newbie :D!

Comment: @Newbie you're welcome dude ! there's no trouble with your questions , i'm appreciated for your good question that forced me to learn new things ! ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> b''.join(chr(ord(a) ^ ord(b)) for a, b in zip(b'abc', b'efg'))
'\x04\x04\x04'
```

Answer (score 1):

Not really efficient, but this should work.

```
s1 = b'abc'
s2 = b'efg'
s3= b''
for c1,c2 in zip(s1, s2):
    s3 += chr( ord(c1) ^ ord(c2) )

>>> s3
'\x04\x04\x04'
```