# Why can't you xor bytes objects in python?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, byte, arrays, bitwise-xor

I think I understand python bytes objects, but supporting bitwise operations on byte strings seems like such an obvious feature. I don't understand why it is not supported.

```
>>>'abcdefg'.encode('ascii')
b'abcdefg'
```

Okay. I went from a string to something like the byte representation of my string in ascii.

So when I try:

```
>>> a = 'abcdefg'.encode('ascii')
>>> a ^ a
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'bytes' and 'bytes'
```

Why? Why doesn't python support this? Is there something I don't understand about bytes objects that makes this unfeasible or ambiguous?

Comment: There are work arounds for this,  Check out this stackoverflow thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612720/how-to-do-bitwise-exclusive-or-of-two-strings-in-python

Comment: @BrianCain I realize there are workarounds. I was asking why it is not supported.

Comment: @BrianCain there is a comment in that question basically saying that python should support this. So maybe the answer is "No, python should do this"?

Comment: Probably no one has proposed a PEP for this yet

Comment: [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2006-March/061980.html) mailing list post seems relevant. The conclusion appears to be "put it in a PEP and we'll think about it"

Comment: defining xor for bytes is not so straightforward if you consider data of different length - see [this](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-October/279803.html) python mailinglist answer for reference

Comment: What should `b'a' ^ b'ab'` evaluate to? I can thing of four options off the top of my head, depending on whether you pad `'a'` to `'\x00a'` or `'a\x00'`, or you return a one-byte answer with `'a'` xor'd with either the first or second byte of `'ab'`.

Comment: @chepner  -- So you cannot conceive of the obvious `ValueError -- array lengths must match`  ???

Comment: That's not much more interesting than the current `TypeError`, so I ignored it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature has been proposed [on the python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/issue19251). And there is proposed patch (which I wrote after being annoyed by this). But the current feedback is negative, and more is needed if it is to be included.

Comment: Wow. Just followed your link, and...what a rabbit-hole that discussion is.  As an embedded coder, it just seems logical to me that if you're in a domain where you need bytes and bytearrays, you're not far off from needing bitwise operations. Sad.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported primarily because it is only rarely needed in "normal" Python code, and by the time you do need it you are probably already using a third-party package, [like NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), that has such things (and more!) built-in and very performant... at least, much more performant than standard Python would be.

Comment: Hello Ethan, NumPy is a heavyweight dependency (it needs a c compiler). And it is not portable to jython, or pypy. So responding to "why doesn't standard python support this"? With "because a heavyweight non-portable third party library already does that" does not seem like a sufficient answer to me.

Also the python cryptographic authority's [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) does not seem to depend on NumPy. So I'm not sure this is even correct.

Comment: @cowlicks: The actual response was "it is only rarely needed in 'normal' Python code".