# Fastest bitwise xor between two multibyte binary data variables

Tags: python, bitwise-operators, multibyte

What is the fastest way to implementat the following logic:

```
def xor(data, key):
    l = len(key)

    buff = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        buff += chr(ord(data[i]) ^ ord(key[i % l]))
    return buff
```

In my case *key* is 20-byte sha1 digest, and *data* is some binary data between 20 bytes and few (1, 2, 3) megabytes long

**UPDATE:**

OK guys. Here's a 3.5 times faster implementation, which splits data and key by chunks of 4, 2 or 1 bytes (in my case, most of the time it's 4-byte long integer):

```
def xor(data, key):
    index = len(data) % 4
    size = (4, 1, 2, 1)[index]
    type = ('L', 'B', 'H', 'B')[index]
    key_len = len(key)/size
    data_len = len(data)/size
    key_fmt = "<" + str(key_len) + type;
    data_fmt = "<" + str(data_len) + type;

    key_list = struct.unpack(key_fmt, key)
    data_list = struct.unpack(data_fmt, data)

    result = []
    for i in range(data_len):
        result.append (key_list[i % key_len] ^ data_list[i])

    return struct.pack(data_fmt, *result)
```

Uses a lot of memory, but in my case it's not a big deal.

Any ideas how to increase the speed few more times? :-)

**FINAL UPDATE:**

OK, ok... numpy did the job. That's just blazing fast:

```
def xor(data, key):
    import numpy, math

    # key multiplication in order to match the data length
    key = (key*int(math.ceil(float(len(data))/float(len(key)))))[:len(data)]

    # Select the type size in bytes       
    for i in (8,4,2,1):
        if not len(data) % i: break

    if i == 8: dt = numpy.dtype('<Q8');
    elif i == 4: dt = numpy.dtype('<L4');
    elif i == 2: dt = numpy.dtype('<H2');
    else: dt = numpy.dtype('B');

    return numpy.bitwise_xor(numpy.fromstring(key, dtype=dt), numpy.fromstring(data, dtype=dt)).tostring()
```

Initial implementation needed 8min 50sec to process a gigabyte, the second - around 2min 30sec and the last one just.... 0min 10sec.

Thanks to anyone who contributed ideas and code. You're great guys!

Comment: The "fastest"? Well, the way with the lowest runtime speed overhead is a C (or Cython, for the weak of heart) extension.

Comment: Create a dict of `key:ord(key)` + `val:ord(val)` (from `set(key) | set(data)`) to save many ord calls? Then use a list comprehension instead of string concatenation?

Comment: There's quite a detailed look at this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119761/simple-python-challenge-fastest-bitwise-xor-on-data-buffers

Comment: The one I just posted takes about 42% of the time of your current fastest one when xoring a 16M string, and substantially less memory. It also does not rely on numpy or inline assembly.

Comment: Also, I have no clue what you intend to do with this, but this is a completely horrible method of doing encryption.

Comment: I added a new version of my code that's much shorter and easier to understand. And yes, it really is a lot faster than the version you currently have as the fastest. Doesn't seem terribly intuitive, I know.

Comment: Re: Your final (& prior) update -- you could generally speed these up by *always* processing as much data as possible using the largest chunk size (4 or 8 bytes) and handling any remainder using an appropriate smaller size (1 or 2 bytes). The later being such a small amount, it might not be worth optimizing.

Comment: @Nikolai Gorchilov I tried your code but getting a datatype error regarding '<Q8', has it changed recently? I googled and found nothing

Comment: Your padding algorithm for extending the key is probably what is adding 9 seconds to your computation. I would optimize the code above as follows: `key = np.pad(key, (0, len(data) - len(key)), 'wrap')`

Answer (score 1):

If `len(data)` is large, you might see a significant improvement from `xrange`. Actually, you can replace the range function entirely with `enumerate`. You might also benefit from using a list instead of appending to a string.

```
def xor(data, key):
    l = len(key)
    buff = []
    for idx, val in enumerate(data):
        buff.append(chr(ord(val) ^ ord(key[idx % l]))
    return ''.join(buff)
```

I haven't timed it, but off the top of my head I'd expect that to be a bit faster for large amounts of data. Make sure you measure every change.

If profiling suggests that the call to `ord()` actually takes time, you can run it on all the values in `key` ahead of time to save a call in the loop.

You could also turn that for loop into a plain old list comprehension, but it will negatively impact readability. Regardless, try it and see if it's way faster.

Comment: No tangible gain with your implementation. But calculating `ord()` for key in advance speeds it up by 10%

Comment: @Nikolai: Well that hardly seems worth it. How about the list comprehension? `''.join([chr(ord(val) ^ ord_key[idx % 1] for idx, val in enumerate(data)])`

Answer (score 1):

Not tested

Don't know if it's faster

supposing that len(mystring) is a multiple of 4

```
def xor(hash,mystring):
    s = struct.Struct("<L")

    v1 = memoryview(hash)

    tab1 = []
    for i in range(5):
        tab1.append(s.unpack_from(v1,i*4)

    v2 = memoryview(mystring)
    tab2=[]
    for i in range(len(mystring)/4):
        tab2.append(s.unpack_from(v1,i*4))
    tab3 = []
    try:
        for i in range(len(mystring)/20):
            for j in range(5):
               tab3.append(s.pack(tab1[j]^tab2[5*i+j]))
    expect IndexError:
        pass
    return "".join(tab3)
```

Comment: 20-30% increase in speed. Nice result, but I need much more :)

Answer (score 1):

This code should work in Python 2.6+ including Py3k.

```
from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
from binascii import unhexlify as _unhexlify


def packl(lnum, padmultiple=0):
    """Packs the lnum (which must be convertable to a long) into a
    byte string 0 padded to a multiple of padmultiple bytes in size. 0
    means no padding whatsoever, so that packing 0 result in an empty
    string.  The resulting byte string is the big-endian two's
    complement representation of the passed in long."""

    if lnum == 0:
        return b'\0' * padmultiple
    elif lnum < 0:
        raise ValueError("Can only convert non-negative numbers.")
    s = hex(lnum)[2:]
    s = s.rstrip('L')
    if len(s) & 1:
        s = '0' + s
    s = _unhexlify(s)
    if (padmultiple != 1) and (padmultiple != 0):
        filled_so_far = len(s) % padmultiple
        if filled_so_far != 0:
            s = b'\0' * (padmultiple - filled_so_far) + s
    return s

def unpackl(bytestr):
    """Treats a byte string as a sequence of base 256 digits
    representing an unsigned integer in big-endian format and converts
    that representation into a Python integer."""

    return int(_hexlify(bytestr), 16) if len(bytestr) > 0 else 0

def xor(data, key):
    dlen = len(data)
    klen = len(key)
    if dlen > klen:
        key = key * ((dlen + klen - 1) // klen)
    key = key[:dlen]
    result = packl(unpackl(data) ^ unpackl(key))
    if len(result) < dlen:
         result = b'\0' * (dlen - len(result)) + result
    return result
```

This will also work in Python 2.7 and 3.x. It has the advantage of being a lot simpler than the previous one while doing basically the same thing in approximately the same amount of time:

```
from binascii import hexlify as _hexlify
from binascii import unhexlify as _unhexlify

def xor(data, key):
    dlen = len(data)
    klen = len(key)
    if dlen > klen:
        key = key * ((dlen + klen - 1) // klen)
    key = key[:dlen]
    data = int(_hexlify(data), 16)
    key = int(_hexlify(key), 16)
    result = (data ^ key) | (1 << (dlen * 8 + 7))
    # Python 2.6/2.7 only lines (comment out in Python 3.x)
    result = memoryview(hex(result))
    result = (result[4:-1] if result[-1] == 'L' else result[4:])
    # Python 3.x line
    #result = memoryview(hex(result).encode('ascii'))[4:]
    result = _unhexlify(result)
    return result
```

Comment: Seems like memoryview is available in python 2.7+ only. Mine is 2.6.5

Comment: @Nikolai Gorchilov: Oh, oops. :-) You can replace `memoryview` with `buffer` in Python 2.6. Alternatively, the first version that has `packl` and `unpackl` doesn't use `memoryview`.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**:As other posters have said, this is a really bad way to encrypt files. [This article](https://blog.malwarebytes.com/threat-analysis/2013/05/nowhere-to-hide-three-methods-of-xor-obfuscation/) demonstrates how to reverse this kind of obfuscation trivially.

first, a simple xor algorithm:

```
def xor(a,b,_xor8k=lambda a,b:struct.pack("!1000Q",*map(operator.xor,
                    struct.unpack("!1000Q",a),
                    struct.unpack("!1000Q",b)))
        ):
    if len(a)<=8000:
        s="!%iQ%iB"%divmod(len(a),8)
        return struct.pack(s,*map(operator.xor,
            struct.unpack(s,a),
            struct.unpack(s,b)))
    a=bytearray(a)
    for i in range(8000,len(a),8000):
        a[i-8000:i]=_xor8k(
            a[i-8000:i],
            b[i-8000:i])
    a[i:]=xor(a[i:],b[i:])
    return str(a)
```

secondly the wrapping xor algorithm:

```
def xor_wrap(data,key,_struct8k=struct.Struct("!1000Q")):
    l=len(key)
    if len(data)>=8000:
        keyrpt=key*((7999+2*l)//l)#this buffer is accessed with whatever offset is required for a given 8k block
        #this expression should create at most 1 more copy of the key than is needed
        data=bytearray(data)
        offset=-8000#initial offset, set to zero on first loop iteration
        modulo=0#offset used to access the repeated key
        for offset in range(0,len(data)-7999,8000):
            _struct8k.pack_into(data,offset,*map(operator.xor,
                _struct8k.unpack_from(data,offset),
                _struct8k.unpack_from(keyrpt,modulo)))
            modulo+=8000;modulo%=l
        offset+=8000
    else:offset=0;keyrpt=key*(len(data)//l+1)#simple calculation guaranteed to be enough
    rest=len(data)-offset
    srest=struct.Struct("!%iQ%iB"%divmod(len(data)-offset,8))
    srest.pack_into(data,offset,*map(operator.xor,
        srest.unpack_from(data,offset),
        srest.unpack_from(keyrpt,modulo)))
    return data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that only uses Python built-in and standard modules which seems very fast -- although I haven't compared it to your numpy version. It uses a couple of optimized conversion functions from the Python Cryptography Toolkit as indicated.

```
# Part of the Python Cryptography Toolkit
# found here:
# http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Y_gnTlD6ECg/trunk/src/gdata/Crypto/Util/number.py&q=lang:python%20%22def%20long_to_bytes%22&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc

# Improved conversion functions contributed by Barry Warsaw, after
# careful benchmarking

import struct

def long_to_bytes(n, blocksize=0):
    """long_to_bytes(n:long, blocksize:int) : string
    Convert a long integer to a byte string.

    If optional blocksize is given and greater than zero, pad the front of the
    byte string with binary zeros so that the length is a multiple of
    blocksize.
    """
    # after much testing, this algorithm was deemed to be the fastest
    s = ''
    n = long(n)
    pack = struct.pack
    while n > 0:
        s = pack('>I', n & 0xffffffffL) + s
        n = n >> 32
    # strip off leading zeros
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] != '\000':
            break
    else:
        # only happens when n == 0
        s = '\000'
        i = 0
    s = s[i:]
    # add back some pad bytes.  this could be done more efficiently w.r.t. the
    # de-padding being done above, but sigh...
    if blocksize > 0 and len(s) % blocksize:
        s = (blocksize - len(s) % blocksize) * '\000' + s
    return s

def bytes_to_long(s):
    """bytes_to_long(string) : long
    Convert a byte string to a long integer.

    This is (essentially) the inverse of long_to_bytes().
    """
    acc = 0L
    unpack = struct.unpack
    length = len(s)
    if length % 4:
        extra = (4 - length % 4)
        s = '\000' * extra + s
        length = length + extra
    for i in range(0, length, 4):
        acc = (acc << 32) + unpack('>I', s[i:i+4])[0]
    return acc


# original code in SO question
def xor_orig(data, key):
    l = len(key)

    buff = ""
    for i in range(0, len(data)):
        buff += chr(ord(data[i]) ^ ord(key[i % l]))
    return buff

# faster pure python version
def xor_new(data, key):
    import math

    # key multiplication in order to match the data length
    key = (key*int( math.ceil(float(len(data))/float(len(key)))))[:len(data)]

    # convert key and data to long integers
    key_as_long = bytes_to_long(key)
    data_as_long = bytes_to_long(data)

    # xor the numbers together and convert the result back to a byte string
    return long_to_bytes(data_as_long ^ key_as_long)

if __name__=='__main__':
    import random
    import sha

    TEST_DATA_LEN = 100000

    data = ''.join(chr(random.randint(0, 255)) for i in xrange(TEST_DATA_LEN))
    key = sha.new(data).digest()

    assert xor_new(data, key) == xor_orig(data, key)
    print 'done'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on my comment in the initial post, you can process large files rather quickly if you stick to `numpy` for key padding and bitwise XOR'ing, like so:

```py
import numpy as np

# ...

def xor(key, data):

    data = np.fromstring(data, dtype=np.byte)
    key = np.fromstring(key, dtype=np.byte)

    # Pad the key to match the data length
    key = np.pad(key, (0, len(data) - len(key)), 'wrap')

    return np.bitwise_xor(key, data)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have is already as fast as you can get in Python.

If you really need it faster, implement it in C.

Comment: I don't think so, I think it could be faster if the xoring thing would be on a long number of 20 bytes long

Comment: Unfortunately I'm very unqualified in C :(

Comment: @xavier: how to implement this?