# Modify a large list without any loops in python

Tags: python, list

My list is:

```
a=[1,2,3,4]
```

Now I want my list to be:

```
a=[-1,-2,-3,-4]
```

How can I change my list this way without using any loops?

Update: this may be a large list, on the order of 10000 elements.

Comment: Any special reason not to loop?

Comment: due to time constraints.. looping takes lots of time. I have to modify the list which has upto 10000 intergers

Comment: Why do you think that a single loop over 10000 integers is your bottleneck issue?  That really won't take very long.

Comment: Note that the answers which use 'map' and a 'lambda' will be slower than just looping. Just 'not looping' won't by itself make your code faster.

Comment: may be you should think of way to NOT negate, so may be can you tell why you want to negate and in that case why loop is slower?

Comment: Food for thought :  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding  (probably doesn't apply to python)

Comment: @Matt, in extreme cases you might unroll a 10000 iteration loop (perhaps if timing is critical in an embedded system for example), but the space/time tradeoff usually isn't worth it beyond say 100. So to do 10000, you might loop through the unrolled part 100 times

Comment: Related: extreme speedups to xor an array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119761/simple-python-challenge-fastest-bitwise-xor-on-data-buffers

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use Python's [map](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) functionality

```
a[:] = map(lambda x: -x, a)
```

Here's the description of the map function from the above link:

> **map(function, iterable, ...)**
>   Apply function to every item of iterable and return a list of the
>   results. If additional iterable arguments are passed, function must
>   take that many arguments and is applied to the items from all
>   iterables in parallel. If one iterable is shorter than another it is
>   assumed to be extended with None items. If function is None, the
>   identity function is assumed; if there are multiple arguments, map()
>   returns a list consisting of tuples containing the corresponding items
>   from all iterables (a kind of transpose operation). The iterable
>   arguments may be a sequence or any iterable object; the result is
>   always a list.

Comment: This won't modify the existing list in place, it will replace the variable `a` with a new list with the answers negated. (Of course this might be acceptable to the OP, but it is a subtle difference.)

Comment: is it significantly faster than loop or list comprehension?

Comment: If instead of assigning with `a = ...` you do `a[:] = ...`, then this *will* change the list in place, by doing a slice assignment. Then other references to this list will see the negated values.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Thanks I didn't know that, updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Alex Martelli showed me the light on this, in his answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating-in-python

Comment: Since you are using a map, it would be better to use a funciont directly instead of a lambda. `import operator` and then `a[:] = map(operator.neg, a)` Also is better in terms of performance.

Answer (score 9):

some quick and dirty benchmarks from ipython

```
In [1]: a=range(10000)

In [2]: import numpy 

In [3]: timeit [-i for i in a]
1000 loops, best of 3: 576 us per loop

In [4]: timeit map(lambda i:-i, a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.68 ms per loop

In [5]: timeit list(-1*numpy.array(a))
100 loops, best of 3: 2.53 ms per loop
```

Note that if `a` can be a numpy array you don't need to wast time on the conversion

```
In [6]: a = numpy.array(a)

In [7]: timeit -- -a
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.4 us per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the numpy library:

```
list(-1*numpy.array(a))
```

Comment: Unfortunately the overheads of converting between Python and numpy make it unsuitable for speeding up single shot operations like that

Answer (score 3):

Well it depends on what you mean by without any loops. In case you just want to avoid explicit loops like

```
a = [ -x for x in a ]
```

you could use the map function, that would loop for you.

```
a = map( lambda x:-x, a)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import operator
a = map(operator.neg, a)
```

Comment: Note that unlike the other answers which use `map` this answer is probably faster than an explicit loop. The other `map` answers all use a `lambda` which will make them slower.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it without loop but you can hide the fact.

```
map(lambda x: -x, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the exact reason why loop is not required and knowing that there is no other efficient way to negate a list here is my super fast solution (I have no knowledge of the context so this may not work)

```
class nlist(object):
    def __init__(self, l):
        self._list = l

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return -self._list[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        for i in self._list:
            yield -i


nl = nlist([1,2,3,4])
for i in nl:
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [-a[0], -a[1], -a[2], -a[3]]
```

Now the problem is that this only works if `a` has exactly 4 items. To generalise to different number of items...well that's what loops are for.