# Getting and replace values from numpy array based on list of index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, slice

is it possible to get values from numpy array based on list of indexes like i.e 1 and 3? Then, I want to put another values instead of them.

Here is example:

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array([0, 1, 2, 8, 4, 9, 1, 2])
idx = [3, 5]
```

So I want to replace X[3] = 8 and X[5] = 9 with another values but I do not want to this in a loop because I could have large array. Is it a way or maybe a function to do operations like this but not in a loop?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437024/modify-a-large-list-without-any-loops-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`np.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy-r):

```
larr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 8, 4, 9, 1, 2])
larr[np.r_[3, 5]]
```

Output

```
array([8, 9])
```

As @MadPhysicist suggest, using `larr[np.array([3, 5])]` will work also, and is faster.

Comment: Why not just `np.array`?

Comment: `larr[np.array([3, 5])]`. Not shorter, but faster

Answer (score 3):

You should use `array[idx] = new_values`. This approach is much faster than native python loops. But you will have to convert 'idx' and 'new_values' to numpy arrays as well.

```
import numpy as np

n = 100000
array = np.random.random(n)
idx = np.random.randint(0, n, n//10)
new_values = np.random.random(n//10)
```

```
%time array[idx] = new_values
```

Wall time: 257 µs

```
def f():
    for i, v in zip(idx, new_values):
        array[i] = v
%time f()
```

Wall time: 5.93 ms