# Bitwise XOR of hexadecimal numbers

Tags: python, hex, bit-manipulation, xor

How can we XOR hexadecimal numbers in Python? For example, I want to XOR `'ABCD'` and `'12EF'`, the answer should be `'B922'`.

I used the code below, but it gives the wrong results.

```py
# xor two strings of different lengths
def strxor(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join(["%s" % (ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join(["%s" % (ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

key = '12ef'
m1 = 'abcd'
print(strxor(key, m1))
```

Comment: Just a hint for `zip`: it does the stripping of the longer argument automatically. Anyway, @unwind is right with his short solution.

Comment: related: [Simple Python Challenge: Fastest Bitwise XOR on Data Buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2119761/4279)

Answer (score 120):

Whoa. You're really over-complicating it by a very long distance. Try:

```
>>> print(hex(0x12ef ^ 0xabcd))
0xb922
```

You seem to be ignoring these handy facts, at least:

- Python has native support for hexadecimal integer literals, with the `0x` prefix.
- "Hexadecimal" is just a presentation detail; the arithmetic is done in binary, and then the result is printed as hex.
- There is no connection between the format of the inputs (the hexadecimal literals) and the output, there is no such thing as a "hexadecimal number" in a Python variable.
- The `hex()` function can be used to convert any number into a hexadecimal string for display.

If you already have the numbers as strings, you can use the `int()` function to convert to numbers, by providing the expected base (16 for hexadecimal numbers):

```
>>> print(int("12ef", 16))
4874
```

So you can do two conversions, perform the XOR, and then convert back to hex:

```
>>> print(hex(int("12ef", 16) ^ int("abcd", 16)))
0xb922
```

Comment: Of course if @pratibha only has string literals then an alternative is `hex(int('12ef', 16) ^ int('abcd', 16))`

Comment: @unwind, the second number should be 0xabcd, hence the expected answer of 0xB922.

Answer (score 11):

If the two hex strings are the same length and you want a hex string output then you might try this.

```
def hexxor(a, b):    # xor two hex strings of the same length
    return "".join(["%x" % (int(x,16) ^ int(y,16)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b)])
```

Answer (score 5):

here's a better function

```
def strxor(a, b):     # xor two strings of different lengths
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join([chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])
```

Comment: Looks like the exact code from one of the assignments in Crypto 1 course on Coursera. ;)

Answer (score 5):

If the strings are the same length, then I would go for `'%x' % ()` of the built-in xor (`^`).

Examples -

```
>>>a = '290b6e3a'
>>>b = 'd6f491c5'
>>>'%x' % (int(a,16)^int(b,16))
'ffffffff'
>>>c = 'abcd'
>>>d = '12ef'
>>>'%x' % (int(a,16)^int(b,16))
'b922'
```

If the strings are not the same length, truncate the longer string to the length of the shorter using a slice `longer = longer[:len(shorter)]`

Answer (score 2):

For performance purpose, here's a little code to benchmark these two alternatives:

```
#!/bin/python

def hexxorA(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return "".join(["%x" % (int(x,16) ^ int(y,16)) for (x, y) in zip(a[:len(b)], b)])
    else:
        return "".join(["%x" % (int(x,16) ^ int(y,16)) for (x, y) in zip(a, b[:len(a)])])

def hexxorB(a, b):
    if len(a) > len(b):
        return '%x' % (int(a[:len(b)],16)^int(b,16))
    else:
        return '%x' % (int(a,16)^int(b[:len(a)],16))

def testA():
    strstr = hexxorA("b4affa21cbb744fa9d6e055a09b562b87205fe73cd502ee5b8677fcd17ad19fce0e0bba05b1315e03575fe2a783556063f07dcd0b9d15188cee8dd99660ee751", "5450ce618aae4547cadc4e42e7ed99438b2628ff15d47b20c5e968f086087d49ec04d6a1b175701a5e3f80c8831e6c627077f290c723f585af02e4c16122b7e2")
    if not int(strstr, 16) == int("e0ff3440411901bd57b24b18ee58fbfbf923d68cd88455c57d8e173d91a564b50ce46d01ea6665fa6b4a7ee2fb2b3a644f702e407ef2a40d61ea3958072c50b3", 16):
        raise KeyError
    return strstr

def testB():
    strstr = hexxorB("b4affa21cbb744fa9d6e055a09b562b87205fe73cd502ee5b8677fcd17ad19fce0e0bba05b1315e03575fe2a783556063f07dcd0b9d15188cee8dd99660ee751", "5450ce618aae4547cadc4e42e7ed99438b2628ff15d47b20c5e968f086087d49ec04d6a1b175701a5e3f80c8831e6c627077f290c723f585af02e4c16122b7e2")
    if not int(strstr, 16) == int("e0ff3440411901bd57b24b18ee58fbfbf923d68cd88455c57d8e173d91a564b50ce46d01ea6665fa6b4a7ee2fb2b3a644f702e407ef2a40d61ea3958072c50b3", 16):
        raise KeyError
    return strstr

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit
    print("Time-it 100k iterations :")
    print("\thexxorA: ", end='')
    print(timeit.timeit("testA()", setup="from __main__ import testA", number=100000), end='s\n')
    print("\thexxorB: ", end='')
    print(timeit.timeit("testB()", setup="from __main__ import testB", number=100000), end='s\n')
```

Here are the results :

```
Time-it 100k iterations :
    hexxorA: 8.139988073991844s
    hexxorB: 0.240523161992314s
```

Seems like `'%x' % (int(a,16)^int(b,16))` is faster then the zip version.