# Split encrypted string and xor it with a shorter string at every point

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, xor

I'm new to Python, but have a decent amount of programming experience (although I don't really know how I would do this in another language either).

I have a long-ish encrypted hex string, and what I would like to do is xor that string with `the` at every position such that I am xor-ing an equal length string from the encrypted string at every point.

For example, if I had the string `12104c06134e5709` and `the` as `74484520` I would like to do:

- `12104c06` xor `74484520`
- `2104c061` xor `74484520`
- `104c0613` xor `74484520`

(etc...)

I'm not overly concerned how the result is stored at this point, I suppose an array would be fine (a list in Python, I think).

Is this possible? Thanks for all help.

Comment: This will help with the XOR http://stackoverflow.com/a/11119660/2282538

Comment: I actually do know how to know how to do the xor part; I should have mentioned that. It's mostly the splitting that I need help with, but thank you.

Comment: Another question:  For your example, should there be 9 XORs that are calculated?  I am working on an answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def iterXOR(hexString, otherString):

    #Convert otherString to a hex (the 16 is for base 16)
    otherNum = int(otherString, 16)

    #Iterate over the hexString
    for i in range(0, len(hexString) - len(otherString) + 1):

        #Grab the substring of length N beginning at index i
        #Where N is the length of otherString and i is the index
        subString = hexString[i:i+len(otherString)]

        #Convert the substring to a hex number
        hexNum = int(subString, 16)

        #Print the product of the XOR (or do whatever you want here)
        print hex(hexNum ^ otherNum)


#Usage
iterXOR("12104c06134e5709", "74484520")
```

Outputs:

```
>>> 
0x66580926
0x554c8541
0x64044333
0x70882414
0x384e566e
0xb42971c5
0x725b0b77
0x157ca050
0x67061229
```

Comment: This definitely works, but I am trying to decode it back to ascii at the end of the function and it is throwing an error...any idea? I basically added this at the end: xor = hex(hexNum ^ otherNum) // print xor.decode("hex")

Comment: Are you using Python 3?  There is no `.decode("hex")` in Python 3 that I am aware of.

Comment: I'm actually on 2.7.6