# how to generate 16 bytes random number in python and xor them

Tags: python, random, xor

Im writing my own version of ssl and in order to create a master key, I need to create 2 random numbers of 16 bytes and xor them.
can someone help me doing so?

Comment: [How random do they need to be](http://www.bishopfox.com/blog/2012/03/ssl-key-generation-weaknesses/)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate random number with the specific length in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2673385) or [Bitwise XOR of hex numbers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119632/bitwise-xor-of-hex-numbers-in-python).  If you don't know how to perform an XOR, do you really think its a good idea to write a TLS library?

Answer (score 7):

i hope you do this for scientific purposes... ssl is **huge**. and - as always in crypto - a lot can go wrong with an implementation... good luck! but as an effort to study/improve e.g. openssl, that would be a very welcome effort!

#### generating random bytes:

starting from python 3.6 there is the [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module in python. `secrets.token_bytes(16)` will output 16 random bytes.

```
from secrets import token_bytes
print(token_bytes(16))
```

for python <= 3.5:

```
import os
print(os.urandom(16))
```

#### xoring bytes

in order to xor the bytes `a` and `b` (which both have length 16)

```
byteorder = "little"
bytesize = 16
tmp_int = int.from_bytes(a, byteorder) ^ int.from_bytes(b, byteorder)
return tmp_int.to_bytes(16, byteorder)
```

Comment: its just a little project I got... little vbersion of ssl, nothing huge. thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
int(os.urandom(16).encode('hex'),16) ^ int(os.urandom(16).encode('hex'),16)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is often operating system and computer (i.e. hardware) specific.

On Linux, you could use `/dev/random` (read 16 bytes from it) but read [random(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) first.

Be very careful, it is a very sensitive issue and a lot of things can go silently wrong.

BTW, I don't think that rewriting SSL from scratch is reasonable (except for learning purposes).