# How to XOR two strings that contain hex numbers in python?

Tags: python, string, hex, xor

I have looked for an answer online, but none of them seem to solve my problem in my way (I know, I'm picky :D).

Here's the deal: I am using the string type to store two hex numbers, because the default integer type in python is not long enough for my purposes. For example like this:

```
S1 = "315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc57ee59418ce7dc6bc41556bdb36bbca3e8774301fbcaa3b83b220809560987815f65286764703de0f3d524400a19b159610b11ef3e"
S2 = "234c02ecbbfbafa3ed18510abd11fa724fcda2018a1a8342cf064bbde548b12b07df44ba7191d9606ef4081ffde5ad46a5069d9f7f543bedb9c861bf29c7e205132eda9382b0bc2c5c4b45f919cf3a9f1cb74151f6d551f4480c82b2cb24cc5b028aa76eb7b4ab24171ab3cdadb8356f"
```

The point is, that these are supposed to be NUMBERS, but they are stored in a string. What I want to do, is to treat these two strings as numbers, perform a bitwise XOR on the two and then get an output in a similar form - a hex number stored in a string.

I am rather new to programming and even newer to python, so I couldn't figure out a way to do this. I am not just looking for a script, I would also like to understand how it works, so please be thorough with your explanation, as I am quite the noob :D.

Comment: You don't have to worry about integer size. Python is smart enough to use its big integer implementation (`long`) when necessary.

Comment: Did you come to the conclusion of Python, not being able to deal with large integers, after first trying to XOR the integers? Or did you just hypothesize?

Comment: call `binascii.unhexlify()` and apply any solution from [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119761/simple-python-challenge-fastest-bitwise-xor-on-data-buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2119761/4279), call `binascii.hexlify()` on the result to get hex string.

Comment: I came to the conclusion by reading it off the Internet :D, someone had a similar problem and his thing wasn't working because apparently python truncated his number when he converted it to the integer type, as the value was too large to fit in. So I blindly believed this and didn't bother to try :D.

Comment: Your strings actually take almost exactly twice as much memory as the equivalent int/long and python allows int/long type to grow up to the maximum available memory.

Answer (score 2):

Python *can* hold your values as numbers.

See this for proof,

```
>>> hex(int(S1, 16))[2:-1] == S1
True
```

I'm simply adjusting the string, removing `'0x'` from the beginning and `L` from the end.

For your answer all you need to do is,

```
hex(int(S1, 16) ^ int(S2, 16))
```

Comment: `because the default integer type in python is not long enough for my purposes` ?

Comment: `int` is too small, but the constructor is actually smart: `type(int(S1, 16)) ... <type 'long'>`

Answer (score 1):

1. Reverse both strings to s1_r and s2_r
2. Do a char by char xor (char1 (from s1_r) xor char2 (from s2_r))
3. Append result to xor_str
4. Reverse xor_str

Comment: The `long` type actually support XOR right away, and it has arbitrary integer size, so it is not necessary to do this manually in Python.

Answer (score 1):

To perform the XOR operation assuming they are long integers, you can use the `long` type in Python:

```
# Convert the hex string S1 and S2 to longs
l1=long(S1,16) 
l2=long(S2,16)
result=hex(l1 ^ l2) # Convert the XOR of the strings
# Output will be:
# '0x1013abb8b0ead34450ee04e8d507fa16552e5aa9f2cc9551acc9d71b646f8a9b4f3548f2068172b201bf0daf75bdddd0dedd861b9ccbcf7c9ce53e39ecafa9c86880fba0c600778fc7bc6e3bd60c8b0df469f5a7f1da4339f9202bdb43b97b22db69642ce5402b8ce44f86d990dbf5a2L'
```

Comment: `l1 = int(s1, 16)` also works fine! Python handles it without you having to bother about its size! `type(int(S1, 16))` -> `<type 'long'>`

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wrote in my comment :)