# How to XOR two hex strings in Python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, hex, xor

I have two strings stored in 2 separate files, `string1="95274DE03C78B0BD"` and `string2="48656c6c6f20576f"`.

How can I do bitwise XOR them in Python 3? I expect to get `DD42218C5358E7D2` as my result. Please note that I don't want to `ord()` the strings, my strings are already in hex.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to XOR two strings that contain hex numbers in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388004/how-to-xor-two-strings-that-contain-hex-numbers-in-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strings in Python 3 are unicode objects and so a string of hexadecimal characters does not correspond to the binary representation of the integer in memory (which you need to use XOR).

With this in mind, you could interpret the strings as base-16 integers first, XOR them, and convert the resulting integer back to a hex string:

```
>>> hex(int(string1, 16) ^ int(string2, 16))
'0xdd42218c5358e7d2'
```

Comment: use: xored[2:]  to get rid of the "0x" in the begining.