# fast XORing bytes in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, xor

I need to xor 2 bytes objects. I use this code:

```
def bxor(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    result = b""
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        result += bytes([b1 ^ b2])
    return result
```

It works fine when the bytes objects are small, but if I xor big objects (a few MB) it takes very long time (a few hours). How can I make it faster?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119761/simple-python-challenge-fastest-bitwise-xor-on-data-buffers) might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When XORing `bytes` objects with one million elements each, this loop creates roughly one million temporary `bytes` objects and copies *each* byte, on average, roughly 500 thousand times from one temporary `bytes` to the next. Note that the exact same problem exists for strings (in many other languages, too). The string solution is to create a list of string parts and use `''.join` at the end to concatenate them efficiently. You can do the same thing with bytes:

```
def bxor(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    parts = []
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        parts.append(bytes([b1 ^ b2]))
    return b''.join(parts)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `bytearray` which is mutable and can therefore avoid the problem. It also allows you to not allocate a new `bytes` object on every iteration, you can just append the byte/`int`.

```
def bxor(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    result = bytearray()
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        result.append(b1 ^ b2)
    return result
```

You can alternatively `return bytes(result)` if you want/need a `bytes` object.

Comment: The `b''.join()` is no faster; in my timings it is actually a little slower..

Comment: I was timing 70 bytes, and added a 7000 bytes test as well. `bytes.join()` improves a little with more bytes.

Comment: `bytes(map(operator.xor, b1, b2))` runs in about half the time in a test with a million bytes.

Answer (score 10):

Adding this in another answer, 'cause it is one:

If you want something faster than the "manual" methods given, there's always Numpy:

```
import numpy

def bxor_numpy(b1, b2):
    n_b1 = numpy.fromstring(b1, dtype='uint8')
    n_b2 = numpy.fromstring(b2, dtype='uint8')

    return (n_b1 ^ n_b2).tostring()
```

and it's fast:

```
first_random = urandom(100000)
second_random = urandom(100000)

min(Timer(partial(bxor_inplace, first_random, second_random)).repeat(10, 100))
#>>> 1.5381054869794752
min(Timer(partial(bxor_append, first_random, second_random)).repeat(10, 100))
#>>> 1.5624085619929247
min(Timer(partial(bxor_numpy, first_random, second_random)).repeat(10, 100))
#>>> 0.009930026979418471
```

So it's 150x faster than the best alternatives posted here.

Answer (score 7):

Using a `bytearray` is a **lot** faster already:

```
def bxor(b1, b2):
    result = bytearray(b1)
    for i, b in enumerate(b2):
        result[i] ^= b
    return bytes(result)
```

A quick `timeit` comparison:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> b1, b2 = b'abcdefg' * 10, b'aaaaaaa' * 10
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor as it', number=10000)
0.9230150280000089
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor_ba as it', number=10000)
0.16270576599890774
```

This avoids creating new `bytes` objects for all the concatenations.

The `b''.join()` method [proposed by delnan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23312662/100297) is no much better than the original version:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor_join as it', number=10000)
0.9936718749995634
```

And a re-run with bytestrings 100 times larger:

```
>>> b1, b2 = b'abcdefg' * 1000, b'aaaaaaa' * 1000
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor as it', number=1000)
11.032563796999966
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor_join as it', number=1000)
9.242204494001271
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor_ba as it', number=1000)
1.762020197998936
```

to show that `bytes.join()` is a faster than repeated concatenation.

A final 7 million byte run, repeated 10 times, just with the `bytearray` version, I ran out of patience with the other versions:

```
>>> b1, b2 = b'abcdefg' * 1000000, b'aaaaaaa' * 1000000
>>> timeit.timeit('it(b1, b2)', 'from __main__ import b1, b2, bxor_ba as it', number=10)
16.18445999799951
```

Comment: It's not simply 9x faster, the gap grows quite fast as the strings grow longer. But it's reassuring that the asymptotically faster option is also faster for small inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Martijn Pieters' timings are a bit different to mine:

```
def bxor_add(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    result = b""
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        result += bytes([b1 ^ b2])
    return result

def bxor_inplace(b1, b2):
    result = bytearray(b1)
    for i, b in enumerate(b2):
        result[i] ^= b
    return bytes(result)

def bxor_join(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    parts = []
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        parts.append(bytes([b1 ^ b2]))
    return b''.join(parts)

def bxor_append(b1, b2): # use xor for bytes
    result = bytearray()
    for b1, b2 in zip(b1, b2):
        result.append(b1 ^ b2)
    return bytes(result)

#>>> 

from os import urandom
from timeit import Timer
from functools import partial

first_random = urandom(200000)
second_random = urandom(200000)

Timer(partial(bxor_add, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 1.3261873809969984
Timer(partial(bxor_inplace, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.03055390200461261
Timer(partial(bxor_join, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.15852201101370156
Timer(partial(bxor_append, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 0.030534288001945242

first_random = urandom(10000000)
second_random = urandom(10000000)

Timer(partial(bxor_inplace, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 1.5432947289955337
Timer(partial(bxor_join, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 7.90503858300508
Timer(partial(bxor_append, first_random, second_random)).timeit(1)
#>>> 1.5145326450001448
```

I'd go with the `append` version for clarity and speed.

---

For clarification, I don't think the `append` method is meaningfully faster than the `inplace` version; I just think it's a tiny bit more straightforward.

Nevertheless, because it was requested:

```
first_random = urandom(100000)
second_random = urandom(100000)

min(Timer(partial(bxor_inplace, first_random, second_random)).repeat(10, 100))
#>>> 1.5381054869794752
min(Timer(partial(bxor_append, first_random, second_random)).repeat(10, 100))
#>>> 1.5196998479950707
```

Comment: `.timeit(1)` is little better than fooling around with `time.time`, you need more iterations to even out noise.

Comment: Normally that would be true, but noise is likely to be tiny (on a log scale) with the size of the operations. In fact `timeit(N)` isn't going to do anything; you want `.repeat`.

Comment: I don't doubt the significance of 7.9 seconds vs. 1.5 seconds but I do doubt the significance of 1.515 seconds versus 1.543 seconds ("I'd do with the `append` version for [...] speed"). And yes, you'd want `repeat()`.

Comment: Oui, but I just treat those as the same number. If the 0.03 seconds matters to you because of the scale of your operations you're better off rewriting this in Numpy.

Comment: The `bytearray.append()` is entirely comparable over 10 runs with 7 million bytes; it doesn't entirely matter which one you pick as long as you use a `bytearray`.

Comment: @Veedrac I also treat them as the same number, and hence (as Marijn said) there is no reason to prefer one bytearray version over the other on basis of speed.