# Python bitwise operation on large binary strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I want to perform bitwise operation on binary strings with length more than 100 zeros and ones. I know i can convert them using something like `int('1'*100, 2)` which prints `1267650600228229401496703205375L` with `L` character at the end. Then use python bitwise operators but I think it's a bad idea to convert them into integer. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why do you think it is a bad idea to do bitwise operations on a Python integer?

Comment: Is it a good idea to convert a 100 or 1000 zero and one into integer? Using bitwise it not my problem, converting is ... @MartijnPieters

Comment: What Martijn Pieters said, a large integer is held as a linked list (like openssl's `BN_*`).  Doing it with an operator over a bignum or chopping it and looping over it yourself ends being the same thing.

Comment: A *string* of `1` and `0` characters is not suitable for efficient bitwise operations, so you'll have to convert *anyway*. Integers are a far more memory efficient option to store that many bits anyway, why would the conversion to Python integers we a problem at all?

Comment: Can you propose an efficient way for using bit wise operation? I can change binary strings data strcuture. @MartijnPieters

Comment: Might be worth having a look at [Bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/).

Comment: It is excellent idea to convert it into an integer. Otherwise you should use ctypes and protend you're working in C. And even then things will become nasty. As you really have one ascii code for 0 and one for 1, or you meant to use \x00 and \x01. Whatever, it is not a way in which it should be done, so do not do it if it is not just an exemplary scientific work.

Comment: Related: [Simple Python Challenge: Fastest Bitwise XOR on Data Buffers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2119761/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you do not like the idea of using integers because it obfuscates your underlying data. Plus it makes it difficult to work with strings that start with '0' (because they trimmed off when converting to an integer), not to mention the subtleties of signed integers and endianness.

Try using the bitarray module, can be installed with pip: `pip install bitarray`.

```
from bitarray import bitarray
ba1 = bitarray('0' + '1'*100)
ba2 = bitarray('1' + '0'*100)

len(ba1)  # 101
len(ba2)  # 101
ba1[0]    # False
ba2[0]    # True

ba1 | ba2  # bitarray('1111111111.......)

# get your string back
ba1.to01()  # "01111111......."
```

I can't speak for the efficiency. But at least it feels clear as to what you are working with.

Also works in python3

Docs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bitarray/0.8.1

Answer (score 3):

Here is one more way to do it optimally.

```
bin(int("1100",2)|int("1010", 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not do bitwise operations on strings of `0`s and `1`s that is plain bad and slow.  You shall convert the strings to actual numbers as then the processing of several bits is done at once.  **There is nothing wrong with**:

```
int('1'*128,2) & int('1'*128,2)
```

But if you already have strings of `0`s and `1`s and you want control over the bitwise operation on parts of the strings.  You can do the following:

```
l = '1'*1024
r = '1'*1024
print map(lambda x: x[0] & x[1], [(int(l[i:i+64], 2), int(r[i:i+64], 2)) for i in range(0,1024,64)])
```

This effectively uses the `&` over small chunks (64 bits) of the string, from left to right.

You can call `bin()` on each result and concatenate them back if you need a string.  (taking care to remove the starting `0b` at the start of the output of `bin()`)

---

python 3 version:

```
l = '1'*1024
r = '1'*1024
print(list(map(lambda x: x[0] & x[1], [(int(l[i:i+64], 2), int(r[i:i+64], 2)) for i in range(0,1024,64)])))
```